# Which versions of SQLite does Zumero work with under Xamarin?

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, zumero

I am exploring Zumero for a new project and attempting to understand which SQLite it works with. Mono.data.sqlite, System.data.sqlite, Sqlite-net, or Sqlite-net Extensions.  I prefer to use the Extensions version however I suspect that it will not work with it or the Sqlite-net because I would be unable to define the tables using the modified Zumero syntax.

I do need to be able to sync multiple smart devices with themselves and with desktop.  Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of our Xamarin component supports (and includes) System.Data.SQLite.

As you suspect, the ORM-ish features of Sqlite-net (and its variants) are not yet supported because Zumero tables need to be created a bit differently than regular tables.  We do plan to implement this functionality, but I cannot yet promise a specific availability date.